# Replace shell32.dll

Tags: windows-7, windows

Installed a custom theme, but it made some changes to my system and now my sound won't work. I backed up the original shell32.dll before doing this, but now I can't delete the new one. Whenever I try to do it, I simply get that it is being used by atieclxx.exe.  I can't teminate that process in order to release shell32.dll. Any help?

Comment: Well, how did you originally replace it?

Comment: That's the weird thing. When I did it the first time, I didn't have any problems as soon as I acquired owner rights. Might be because it was the original or something?

Comment: Do "*the old switcheroo*". Rename `shell32.dll` to `shell32.dl_`. Then put your backup `shell32.dll` in that folder and reboot. Sometimes you can't delete a file but rename it just fine. I find it, however, very curios to begin with to mess with that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Betting "atieclxx" is an ATI display driver or control panel component.  Stop any ATI software from running and see if you have better luck.  Also you might try exchanging the file in Safe mode.  If all else fails, use a Windows PE boot disk or Linux live CD to replace the file with Windows not running.

Comment: Safe mode wasn't working, however, I was able to replace the file using dual boot of Linux

Answer (score 1):

If you can't or don't want to use Linux, get [MoveFile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556) from Microsoft and open a command prompt as elevated administrator:

```
movefile.exe C:\Windows\System32\shell32_original.dll C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll
```

confirm the pending move:

```
pendmoves.exe
```

and reboot your machine.